# Need help in designing a phone book application on python running on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulk-load

Hi I want some help in building a Phone book application on python and put it on google app engine. I am running a huge db of 2 million user lists and their contacts in phonebook. I want to upload all that data from my servers directly onto the google servers and then use a UI to retrieve the phone book contacts of each user based on his name.

I am using MS SQL sever 2005 as my DB.

Please help in putting together this application.

Your inputs are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For building your UI, AppEngine has [it's own web framework](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/) called webapp that is pretty easy to get working. I've also had a good experience using the [Jinja2 templating engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/), which you can include in your source, or [package as a zip file](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django10_zipimport.html) (example shows Django, you can do the same type of thing for Jinja).

As for loading all of your data into the DataStore, you should take a look at the [bulk uploader documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to be more specific as to what problem you're having. As far as bulk loading goes, there's lots of bulkloader documentation around; or are you asking about model design? If so, we need to know more about how you plan to search for users. Do you need partial string matches? Sorting? Fuzzy matching?

Comment: Yes I would like to know a model design to upload the data to the google servers and then use that data in a UI where I would like to display the contacts of a user by doing string match of the username.
I have two tables- user,contacts. User table contains the registration details of the users and contacts table has the phonebook of each user.